# Getting statistics from data according to a list of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big list of tickets. These tickets have a create date, and a complete date. I am trying to get a historical list of how many tickets were open on a given day. i.e. for an arbitrary date in a sequential list of dates, how many tickets were opened before (or on) that day, and closed after it (or have null close date).

The relevant columns in dbo.wh_task look like this:

```
task_number         create_time                 date_completed   
T20180619.0041      2018-06-19 19:37:24.727     2018-06-26 23:36:21.613
T20180619.0048      2018-06-19 20:41:07.800     2018-06-27 19:26:43.480
...                 ...                         ...
```

I've gotten this far:

```
DECLARE @Dates table (
  day DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (day)
)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2016-01-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = CAST(GetDate() as DATE)

WHILE ( @dIncr < @dEnd )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Dates (day) VALUES( @dIncr )
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr )


-- --------------------------------
SELECT
  @Dates.day,
  COUNT(tickets.task_number) AS CountOfOpenTickets
FROM @Dates 
LEFT JOIN dbo.wh_task tickets ON Dates.day BETWEEN tickets.create_time AND tickets.date_completed
```

When I run the code, I get `SQL Error (102): Incorrect syntax near 'date_completed'.`
I'm not really sure where to go from here as the error isn't overly descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, improper use of aliases for @dates table in your query and missing `group by` clause for aggregate function `Count`. You can try this query. Also make sure that you have `END` for the `WHILE` loop.

```
SELECT
  d.day,
  COUNT(tickets.task_number) AS CountOfOpenTickets
FROM @Dates as d
LEFT JOIN dbo.wh_task tickets ON d.day BETWEEN tickets.create_time AND tickets.date_completed
group by d.day
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone googling wants to see the working code. Thanks Vinit!

```
DECLARE @Dates table (
  day DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (day)
)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2016-01-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = CAST(GetDate() as DATE)

WHILE ( @dIncr <= @dEnd)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Dates (day) VALUES( @dIncr )
  SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr )
END

-- --------------------------------
SELECT
  dates.day,
  COUNT(tickets.task_number) AS CountOfOpenTickets
FROM @Dates as dates
LEFT JOIN dbo.wh_task tickets ON (dates.day >= tickets.create_time) AND ((dates.day < tickets.date_completed) OR (tickets.date_completed IS NULL))
GROUP BY dates.day
ORDER BY dates.day DESC
```